# jQuery .blur() not being affected - why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I googled this question and couldn't find an answer.

I am trying to have an alert appear when a user unfocuses off of any input on my form.  I discovered the blur and focusout function so my code looks like:

```
$("input").blur(function() {
    alert("Unfocused");
});
```

This works for my input fields no problem.  But for my radio button inputs it doesn't work.  I looked through the docs and google and couldn't figure out why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("input:radio").blur(function() {
    alert("Unfocused");
});
```

Test this code.

[image]

Test with text and radio..

[image]

**THIS DOESN'T WORK IN SAFARI AND CHROME BECAUSE THEY ARE WEBKIT BASED.**

Comment: This does nothing except for now the blur isn't doing when the input text fields are unfocused.  But that is to be selected as the input:radio just focuses on radio fields.

Comment: Can you post you HTML please, what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Ok, you first have to click on radio button, and then on other input field. You should then get "Unfocused" message, http://pokit.etf.ba/get/14a07b7b72ccb00ff432e1cdf3bd5140.jpg , that is case with every input.

Comment: I am literally C&Ping your code and it still won't work for radio buttons.  It works the way I want it to for text fields but not radio buttons.  Blur is what I want to work, not mouse out.  The HTML of the radio button is: <input type="radio" class="class-response" name="q2" value="0" /> False<br /> 
I've even tried $(".class-response").  Doesn't work either.

Comment: Just tried with input, input:radio, and .class-response, everything works, what browser are you using? http://pokit.etf.ba/get/d093e42b65b4faa357e0918edcfac080.jpg

Comment: Ok, it doesn't work in Chrome8 for me, even in IE6 it works, in Opera 10 and Firefox 3.6 it also works.

Comment: Oh, didn't think about testing in other browsers.  I am in Chrome on a mac.  Testing on Firefox it works.  But then now I want to have it work on Chrome.

Comment: It doesn't work in Safari and Chrome because they are Webkit engine based, blur event is not supported ;)

Comment: Damn.  Well that solves the problem.  I thought jQuery was made to have javascript work in all browsers.

Comment: And probably doesn't work in Arora, Web Browser for Android (mobile device platform), BOLT browser, Google Chrome, Epiphany (web browser), Flock (version 3.0 and above), iCab (version 4 uses WebKit; earlier versions used its own rendering engine), Iris Browser, Konqueror (version 4 can use WebKit as an alternative to its native KHTML[19]), Rekonq, Midori, OmniWeb, OWB, Safari, Shiira etc etc :) If you think problem is solved accept as correct answer. Nothing can be 100% cross browser compatible, jQuery is great ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just put `:` before like this:

```
$(":input").blur(function() {
    alert("Unfocused");
});
```

The `:input` filter selector selects all type of inputs.

**From Docs:**

> Description: Selects all input,
>   textarea, select and button elements.

http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

---

To select radio only, you should use `:radio` filter selector instead:

```
$(":radio").blur(function() {
    alert("Unfocused");
});
```

To get little speed gain, you should prepend keyword `input` like this:

```
$("input:radio").blur(function() {
    alert("Unfocused");
});
```

**More Info:**

http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/

---

Here are more `form` selectors:

Form Selectors

There are a few selectors for form elements:

```
* :input Selects all form elements (input, select, textarea, button).
* :text Selects all text fields (type="text").
* :password Selects all password fields (type="password").
* :radio Selects all radio fields (type="radio").
* :checkbox Selects all checkbox fields (type="checkbox").
* :submit Selects all submit buttons (type="submit").
* :image Selects all form images (type="image").
* :reset Selects all reset buttons (type="reset").
* :button Selects all other buttons (type="button").
* :file Selects all <input type="file">.
```

Comment: With the :input it selects the inputs boxes but still not the radio button buttons.

Comment: @Josh Weissbock: Nope, it also selects radio buttons, you cat test here: http://jsbin.com/azucu3 and http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Comment: No, I mean, I tried :input but the radio buttons were still not being set off on blur.  As per my inital question.